# Shadow not appearing for UIView using CALayer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

I have a subclassed `UIView` loaded from a nib, and I cannot get a shadow to draw around it.  I'm trying to get a shadow to appear around the entire view for quite some time now.  I elected to place it in it's own sublayer to simplify animating it later.  Here's the code:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib 
{
    self.clipsToBounds = NO;

    // set up the shadow layer
    CALayer *shadow = [CALayer layer];
    shadow.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    shadow.shadowRadius = 15.0;
    shadow.opacity = 1.0;
    [self.layer addSublayer:shadow];
    // I set this property so I have access to it later to more easily animate it.
    self.shadowLayer = shadow;
}
```

When I `NSLog` the `shadowLayer` property, the coordinates and frame are correct.  It's matches the view it's backing.

I also set a border color and corner radius on `self.layer` and it appears correctly.  If I put the shadow on `self.layer` it appears but it encompasses all the subviews of my parent `UIView`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am assuming you have `QuartzCore` imported. I think you need to set & create a border to the `UIView`. The way to use this `[self roundedLayerWithShadow:yourView.layer radius:5.0f];`

```
- (void)roundedLayerWithShadow:(CALayer *)viewLayer 
                        radius:(float)r 
{
    [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [viewLayer setCornerRadius:r];        
    [viewLayer setBorderColor:[RGB(180, 180, 180) CGColor]];
    [viewLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];

    [viewLayer setShadowColor:[RGB(0, 0, 0) CGColor]];
    [viewLayer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
    [viewLayer setShadowOpacity:1];
    [viewLayer setShadowRadius:2.0];
    return;
}
```

Comment: What if I have two shadows?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same, and it turns out you need to set `shadowOpacity` to 1.0. In your code you accidentally use `opacity` instead of `shadowOpacity`. That's the same issue I had.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for the shadow to appear:

- the **shadowOpacity** should be larger than 0
- the **shadowRadius** should be larger than 0
- the **masksToBounds** should be set to false (to avoid the clipping of the shadow)
- the **shadowColor** should be different than the background color of the view's superview

Swift 4.2. example implementation:

```
let myCustomView = MyCustomView()
myCustomView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
myCustomView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
myCustomView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
myCustomView.layer.masksToBounds = false
myCustomView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
```

Answer (score -2):

Aside from `borderRadius`, your `shadow` layer looks very much transparent. Therefore it will not drop any shadow on `shadow.superlayer`.

Comment: The shadow is blue and opaque. No reason it shouldn't be visible, as far as I can tell.